# Contents of "androidmanifest.xml" gets errased when importing MyFirstApp

Tags: adt

Win 8.1
JAVA-ADT ver 22.3 first installed last week with updates
Android SDK Manager used to get needed files for JellyBean

I followed the instructions for creating MyFirstApp.
It worked just fine until I "Close all" then "delete" project from Package Explorer.
When Importing or New-project-Android project from existing code-root directory-Copy project into workspace using MyFirstApp the "Androidmanifest.xml" and ".project" files contents are completely erased. It loads with major manifest errors once then never again with no way getting the MyFirstApp reloaded.

I have only one Workspace folder for projects and tried creating several versions like MySecondApp, MyThirdApp and so on.  All get manifest.xml contents erased.

I'm unable to get a project reloaded into JAVA-ADT without it erasing contents in androidmanifest.xml and .project.  This is my first try at JAVA-ADT.

I tried "project" "Clean" before closing out the original MyFirstApp with no success either.
I have read and read posts but can't figure it out.  Lots of hours on developer.android.com training too.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your IDE, is it Eclipse ? If so, when you are importing did you follow these steps ? File -> Import -> in the dialog box use Android -> Existing Android Code into Workspace. You have to choose the root folder of the project. My environment is Android SDK Tools 22.3 & Android SDK Platform-tools 19.0.1.

Comment: Thanks for help. Yes, using Android SDK Tools 22.3 & Android SDK tools 19.0.1.  I tried your solution and got the same bad results. Contents of antroidmanifest.xml deleted. This time I pointed to the root directory of MyFirstApp which is a sub directory of Workspace directory with no success.  any more thoughts?